# The way of Apache Camel Request and Response Logging Globally in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I would like to log all http request and response in Apache Camel with Spring Boot in a global way.
I have tried the class in below. I catched all http request. However, the response can not get logged. Is there a way to log all http response globally in Apache Camel?

```
public class HttpLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
... bla bla. ...
```

Thanks in advance.